# Vertically Center Two Lines of Text Between Two Images

Tags: html, css

```
<body>
  <div id="banner">
     <img id="img1" src="leftimage.gif" alt="" width="" id="headImg" />
      <p id="myText">First Line of Text here
              <br />
              Second Line of Text here
      </p>
     <img id="img2" src="rightimage.gif" alt="" width="" id="headImg2" />
</div>
```

. . . more stuff down here

In CSS I have float: left for img1. On img2 I have float: right; and clear left;

I've been playing with this for hours with no success. What I'd like to do using CSS is center vertically the text between these two images. I'd also like to place it up against the left image, maybe a few pixels off.
Additionally I want to be able to set the font-size and other attributes (bold, color, etc.) of each of the two lines of text.

Can someone please put me on the right track? Nearly everything I try puts the text under the banner div completely. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the p tag after the images, it will float up between the images and you can position it accordingly. You don't need clear:left on the right image and keep in mind that you can only have one id attribute on an element, not two. The images have two ids in your code, so I removed one.

```
<div id="banner">
<img id="img1" src="leftimage.gif" alt=""/>
<img id="img2" src="rightimage.gif" alt="" />
<p id="myText">First Line of Text here
          <br />
          Second Line of Text here
</p>
</div>

#img1{
float:left;
}

#img2{
float:right;
}
```

You can see this working here: http://jsfiddle.net/duq6R/

Answer (score 0):

First off, you will need to remove the floats on the images and paragraph.

Second, you need to make both images and paragraphs `display:inline-block;`. Now, you can use `vertical-align: middle;` to achieve your desired effect.

```
#banner {
    overflow: hidden; /*this is a cheap clearfix*/
    text-align: center;
}
#banner img, p {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[See this JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chippper/v8k5x/).